# Deadlock Application performance implication

Tags: multithreading, performance, deadlock

I understand what deadlock is however I'm looking for what types of application implication it can cause and why there is so much research gone into looking at how to avoid it.

Comment: You never understand what a deadlock is until I tell you!

Comment: Well, a part of or all your application will stop doing anything but waiting for a lock that will never become available...

Comment: A deadlock can have one implication and that's a deadlock. Deadlock prevention/avoidance is another thing

Comment: you should ask something more specific ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, 
There are options available in .net. Moniter.TryEnter method , you can specify the time limit till the CLR will wait to acquire the  lock and if not able to do this , will throw exception . This is the most common deadlock detection technique.

Another one would be using resource dependency graph , if a cycle would be found in the graph than it will most probably result in deadlock.